# Call a loop query from a second table while in a already running query loop

Tags: php, mysql, loops, while-loop

Alright, so I've been foraging through the web as well as stackoverflow for sometime for an answer to my question(below), however nearly every explanation and/or topic I've found is either too convoluted for me or doesn't cater to my specific needs...

In short I have a blog that outputs numerous POSTs. Each POST contains multiple IMAGES. The POST contains data like TITLE, DESCRIPTION, POST DATE.. These things are contained in ONE Table called **tbl_blog**. The IMAGES belong to their own table called **tbl_blog_imgs**.

Right now, my code "works", however it only displays *one* blog post with images that match that blog post's ID. (In **tbl_blog_imgs**, I have a row called blog_key that matches the ID of each entry in **tbl_blog**)

Problem is naturally that I have more than one blog post and only one seems to post...
IN

My Code...

```
<?php

require('myownsecretfile.php');

$sql = "SELECT blog_id, blog_title, blog_desc, date_format(blog_post_date,'%d/%m/%Y') as blog_post_date ";
$sql .= "FROM tbl_blog ";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $blog_id = $row['blog_id']; 
    $blog_title = $row['blog_title']; 
    $blog_desc = $row['blog_desc'];
    $blog_post_date = $row['blog_post_date'];       

    ?>

    <div class="blog-title"><a href="blog_more.php?blog_title=<?php echo $blog_title; ?>"><?php echo $blog_title; ?></a>
    <p class="blog-post-date-style">-&nbsp;<?php echo $blog_post_date; ?>&nbsp;-</p>
    <br>
    <div class="blog-desc">
    <p class="blog-description-style"><?php echo $blog_desc; ?></p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <br>

    <?php

    $sql = "SELECT * ";
    $sql .= "FROM tbl_blog_imgs ";
    $sql .= "WHERE blog_img_key='$blog_id' ";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $blog_img_key = $row['blog_img_key'];   
        $blog_img_path = $row['blog_img_path']; 
        $blog_img_alt = $row['blog_img_alt'];
        $blog_img_title = $row['blog_img_title'];       

        ?>

        <img src="images/blog/<?php echo $blog_img_path; ?>" alt="<?php echo $blog_img_alt; ?>" title="<?php echo $blog_img_title; ?>"><br>


        <?php
    }
}   
?>
```

Must I perform an INNER JOIN? If not, what would be the smartest and most efficient way of acheiving a loop inside of a loop...

Comment: Try group_concat, and explode the array according to your need

Comment: It's hard to tell from the way you formatted your post. Is the second loop nested inside the first loop? If so, I think it should work.

Comment: With nested loops should you be using the same variable for inner and outer loops for the results of the query?

Comment: yea, it's all one continuous chunk of code... I just inserted the text to clarify what was going on (not that the most on here need that...) In that case, I'll edit it to be more simple.

Comment: I knew it was one continuous piece of code, but it's hard to tell whether they're nested because you didn't use proper indentation.

Comment: yea, sorry. sometimes i still have trouble formatting the code and the text as separate things...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the same variable `$result` for both queries. So when it finishes displaying all the images for the first blog, and returns to the beginning of the outer loop, it does

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```

But now `$result` contains the result of the image query, not the blog query. And since that query has returned all its rows, this returns `false`, so the outer loop terminates.

Change them to `$result_blog` and `$result_img` and I think your problem should be solved.

It's also confusing to use the same variable `$row` for both loops. In this case it doesn't cause a problem, because you immediately set variables to the elements of those arrays. But it's a bad habit, so I suggest you rename them as well.

Comment: Thank you. As I'm still learning, I didn't even consider how $result is a variable and not an element... ^^